# In MySQL having issues while fetching data from two tables via performing joining on JSON column

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter-3

I have two tables users and usergroups and there is no hard relationship between them. users table contains an usergroup column which holds multiple usergroup_id from usergroups table in JSON format and usergroups table contains id and usergroup_title columns. Now the requirement is to get the list of all users via a single query which should contain the user data, usergroup_title from usergroups table corresponding to the JSON values.

I had tried with the below query but I am getting an error that JSON_CONTAINS function does not exists. The code is below:

```
SELECT 
u.user_id,
g.id,
g.usergroup_title
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN usergroups g on JSON_CONTAINS(u.usergroup_id, CAST(g.id as JSON), '$')
```

I am getting an error JSON_CONTAINS function does not. I want the data in below format:

```
array("user_id" => 1, "usergroup" => ["admin", "customer", "seller"])
```

Comment: What version of `mysql` are you using? I think you need 5.7 or higher or `mariadb` 10.2.3 or higher.

Comment: Yes, I want it for mariadb 10.1.* .

Comment: Well, you might be able to do it but storing data in this way breaks the [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).  I don't recommend it.

Comment: I know James that this is violating the 1NF, but the requirement is for updating the existing codes not upgrading so need a solution with existing environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we know it's a horrible way to deal with many to one relation, let's get on with the dirt  :

```
SELECT 
u.user_id,
g.id,
g.usergroup_title
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN usergroups g on u.usergroup_id LIKE CONCAT('%"',g.id,'"%')
```

It should do the trick IF your ids are treated as string in your JSON, else you'll need to replace the `'%"'`and `'"%'` parts with something like `'%:'` and `',%'`.